# How to find specific HTML element after CSS selector with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I am trying to retrieve the last img scr of a web page doing webscraping with `BeautifulSoup`. So far I am trying to use a selector but it if impossible for me to find anything after the `::before` selector.

The basic code is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.session()
r = s.get("https://www.immobiliare.it/vendita-case/milano/forlanini/?criterio=dataModifica&ordine=desc")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

for property in soup.find_all("li", {"class": "nd-list__item in-realEstateResults__item"}):
```

The HTML code of the page has the following structure:

Each `li class="nd-list__item in-realEstateResults__item"` is a property I want to extract the img src from.

[image: Each li class="nd-list__item in-realEstateResults__item" is a property I want to extract the img src from]

Bear in mind that the first image has an easier html code, I cannot get the src from the rest of them

Comment: The html code is not valid. The `class` attribute does not close in line 6 nor does it in all subsequent `div`. Even the `div` elements do not close correctly.

Comment: If you know it's the last image, why not use `soup.find_all('img')[-1]['src']`?

Comment: It is a example code, the html code is much more larger in complex, however this part have this exactly structure. The soup.find_all('img') does not find that image.

Comment: you lost closing quotes in class `nd-slideshow__item`

Comment: Maybe element / slideshow is created dynamically via JS? Have you checked your `soup` if it is available there?

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Checking your `soup`? Simply `print(soup)` and you will see what you get back and can work on.

Comment: The img <> does not appear in the soup, this is why I think i need to select more thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### EDIT

**I have to correct my initial statement**:

The use of the rather **sluggish `selenium` is not absolutely necessary** and it is also possible to implement it using `requests` and `beautifulsoup`.

On closer inspection, it turned out that all the information can be found in a `<script>`. Its content can be extracted and used as JSON, and the urls of the maps have to be assembled based on the location information.

##### Example

```
import requests, json, time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = []

url = f'https://www.immobiliare.it/vendita-case/milano/forlanini/?criterio=dataModifica&ordine=desc'

while True:

    jsonData = json.loads(
        BeautifulSoup(
            requests.get(url).text
        ).select_one('#__NEXT_DATA__').text
    )['props']['pageProps']['dehydratedState']['queries'][0]['state']['data']['pages'][0]



    for e in jsonData['results']:
        l = e['realEstate']['properties'][0]['location']
        data.append({
            'id':e['realEstate']['id'],
            'map':f"https://maps.im-cdn.it/static?zoom=15&size=360x270&language=it&style=feature%3Aroad%7Celement%3Alabels%7Cvisibility%3Aoff&sensor=false&markers=icon%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fs1.immobiliare.it%2F_next%2Fstatic%2Fmedia%2Fmap-marker.27fc2b6f.png%7C{l['latitude']}%2C{l['longitude']}&center={l['latitude']}%2C{l['longitude']}"
        })

    print(f"scraping page: {jsonData['currentPage']}")

    if jsonData['maxPages'] != jsonData['currentPage']:
        url = f"https://www.immobiliare.it/vendita-case/milano/forlanini/?criterio=dataModifica&ordine=desc&pag={jsonData['currentPage']+1}"
    else:
        break

    time.sleep(1)

data
```

---

**Older Answer**

As mentioned in the comments, content is rendered dynamically, so you will not get the expected result in used combination of `requests`, that will not render `JS`, like a browser will do, and `BeautifulSoup` that won`t find your expected elements, cause they are not there.

Just to clarify [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) is a pseudo-element:

> In CSS, ::before creates a pseudo-element that is the first child of the selected element. It is often used to add cosmetic content to an element with the content property. It is inline by default.

---

You could go with `requests` if you will use an api, some information comes from:

```
s.get('https://www.immobiliare.it/api-next/agencies/local-expert/?city-id=8042&province-id=MI&macrozone-id[0]=10294&limit=25&output=json').json()

->  {'agencies': [{'id': 9681, 'displayName': 'Fonte Immobiliare Città Studi 2', 'imageUrls': {'large': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/934856533.jpg', 'small': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/934856531.jpg'}, 'agencyUrl': 'https://www.immobiliare.it/agenzie-immobiliari/9681/fonte-citta-studi--milano/', 'address': 'Via Giovanni Briosi 10 20133 - Milano', 'bannerImage': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/image/934857363/xs-c.jpg', 'externalId': None, 'timeContract': 11, 'paid': True}, {'id': 83565, 'displayName': 'Cfc Immobiliare ', 'imageUrls': {'large': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/244109821.jpg', 'small': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/244109817.jpg'}, 'agencyUrl': 'https://www.immobiliare.it/agenzie-immobiliari/83565/cfc-milano/', 'address': 'Via Carnia 7 20132 - Milano', 'bannerImage': 'https://maps.im-cdn.it/static?center=45.492900,9.236340&zoom=15&size=400x230&markers=45.492900,9.236340', 'externalId': None, 'timeContract': 10, 'paid': True}, {'id': 208668, 'displayName': 'YOUR HOME - Real Estate', 'imageUrls': {'large': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/1127494478.jpg', 'small': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/1127494476.jpg'}, 'agencyUrl': 'https://www.immobiliare.it/agenzie-immobiliari/208668/your-home-milano/', 'address': 'Bastioni Porta Nuova 21 20121 - Milano', 'bannerImage': 'https://maps.im-cdn.it/static?center=45.480100,9.188150&zoom=15&size=400x230&markers=45.480100,9.188150', 'externalId': None, 'timeContract': 7, 'paid': True}, {'id': 231505, 'displayName': 'Homepanda', 'imageUrls': {'large': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/693409659.jpg', 'small': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/693409657.jpg'}, 'agencyUrl': 'https://www.immobiliare.it/agenzie-immobiliari/231505/homepanda/', 'address': 'Via Gian Giacomo Mora 20 20123 - Milano', 'bannerImage': 'https://maps.im-cdn.it/static?center=45.458900,9.179330&zoom=15&size=400x230&markers=45.458900,9.179330', 'externalId': None, 'timeContract': 4, 'paid': True}, {'id': 118081, 'displayName': 'CONSULOVEST  CORBETTA Via Meroni 2 - MILANO V.le San Gimignano 8', 'imageUrls': {'large': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/1162882814.jpg', 'small': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/1162882812.jpg'}, 'agencyUrl': 'https://www.immobiliare.it/agenzie-immobiliari/118081/consulovest-corbetta/', 'address': 'Via Meroni 2 20011 - Corbetta', 'bannerImage': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/image/1162882818/xs-c.jpg', 'externalId': None, 'timeContract': None, 'paid': False}, {'id': 5272, 'displayName': 'Arena Immobiliare S.R.L.', 'imageUrls': {'large': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/936162495.jpg', 'small': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/936162493.jpg'}, 'agencyUrl': 'https://www.immobiliare.it/agenzie-immobiliari/5272/arena-milano/', 'address': 'Via Marco Bruto 9 20138 - Milano', 'bannerImage': 'https://maps.im-cdn.it/static?center=45.459800,9.238870&zoom=15&size=400x230&markers=45.459800,9.238870', 'externalId': None, 'timeContract': 21, 'paid': False}, {'id': 32741, 'displayName': 'Studio emme3 ', 'imageUrls': {'large': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/196647202.jpg', 'small': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/196647201.jpg'}, 'agencyUrl': 'https://www.immobiliare.it/agenzie-immobiliari/32741/studio-emme-milano/', 'address': 'Via Pompeo Neri 2 20146 - Milano', 'bannerImage': 'https://maps.im-cdn.it/static?center=45.456800,9.143770&zoom=15&size=400x230&markers=45.456800,9.143770', 'externalId': None, 'timeContract': 4, 'paid': False}, {'id': 242120, 'displayName': 'Levia SRL', 'imageUrls': {'large': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/843934046.jpg', 'small': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/843934044.jpg'}, 'agencyUrl': 'https://www.immobiliare.it/agenzie-immobiliari/242120/levia-milano/', 'address': 'Viale Ungheria 20 20138 - Milano', 'bannerImage': 'https://maps.im-cdn.it/static?center=45.445700,9.246040&zoom=15&size=400x230&markers=45.445700,9.246040', 'externalId': None, 'timeContract': 3, 'paid': False}, {'id': 396994, 'displayName': 'Affiliato Tecnorete: STUDIO IMMOBILIARE CORSICA SRL', 'imageUrls': {'large': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/1247888668.jpg', 'small': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/1247888664.jpg'}, 'agencyUrl': 'https://www.immobiliare.it/agenzie-immobiliari/396994/tecnorete-milano-viale-ungheria/', 'address': 'Viale Ungheria 24 20135 - Milano', 'bannerImage': 'https://maps.im-cdn.it/static?center=45.445500,9.246760&zoom=15&size=400x230&markers=45.445500,9.246760', 'externalId': None, 'timeContract': 0, 'paid': False}, {'id': 140950, 'displayName': 'Abitare Agency Srl', 'imageUrls': {'large': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/1135165888.jpg', 'small': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/1135165886.jpg'}, 'agencyUrl': 'https://www.immobiliare.it/agenzie-immobiliari/140950/abitare-agency/', 'address': 'Via Voghera 7 20144 - Milano', 'bannerImage': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/image/1135165932/xs-c.jpg', 'externalId': None, 'timeContract': 10, 'paid': False}, {'id': 94305, 'displayName': 'Affiliato Tecnocasa: IMMOBILIARE MARGOT SRLU', 'imageUrls': {'large': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/1135591154.jpg', 'small': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/1135591152.jpg'}, 'agencyUrl': 'https://www.immobiliare.it/agenzie-immobiliari/94305/tecnocasa-milano-via-mecenate/', 'address': 'Via Mecenate 4 20138 - Milano', 'bannerImage': 'https://maps.im-cdn.it/static?center=45.457400,9.242440&zoom=15&size=400x230&markers=45.457400,9.242440', 'externalId': None, 'timeContract': 8, 'paid': False}, {'id': 241224, 'displayName': 'INVIMIT SGR SpA', 'imageUrls': {'large': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/829818360.jpg', 'small': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/829818358.jpg'}, 'agencyUrl': 'https://www.immobiliare.it/agenzie-immobiliari/241224/invimit-roma/', 'address': 'Via di Santa Maria in Via 12 00187 - Roma', 'bannerImage': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/image/825106468/xs-c.jpg', 'externalId': None, 'timeContract': 3, 'paid': False}, {'id': 209778, 'displayName': 'STUDIO6ERRE - Sede Milano', 'imageUrls': {'large': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/937464013.jpg', 'small': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/937464011.jpg'}, 'agencyUrl': 'https://www.immobiliare.it/agenzie-immobiliari/209778/studioerre-milano/', 'address': 'Viale Abruzzi 80 20131 - Milano', 'bannerImage': 'https://maps.im-cdn.it/static?center=45.483700,9.217150&zoom=15&size=400x230&markers=45.483700,9.217150', 'externalId': None, 'timeContract': 7, 'paid': False}, {'id': 166328, 'displayName': 'HB ADVISORY', 'imageUrls': {'large': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/311765482.jpg', 'small': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/311765478.jpg'}, 'agencyUrl': 'https://www.immobiliare.it/agenzie-immobiliari/166328/hb-advisory/', 'address': 'Corso Buenos Aires 60 20124 - Milano', 'bannerImage': 'https://maps.im-cdn.it/static?center=45.482200,9.212750&zoom=15&size=400x230&markers=45.482200,9.212750', 'externalId': None, 'timeContract': 9, 'paid': False}, {'id': 41477, 'displayName': 'StudioZimer', 'imageUrls': {'large': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/1143272706.jpg', 'small': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/1143272704.jpg'}, 'agencyUrl': 'https://www.immobiliare.it/agenzie-immobiliari/41477/studiozimer/', 'address': 'CORSO LODI 111 20135 - Milano', 'bannerImage': 'https://maps.im-cdn.it/static?center=45.441500,9.221210&zoom=15&size=400x230&markers=45.441500,9.221210', 'externalId': None, 'timeContract': 4, 'paid': False}, {'id': 386016, 'displayName': 'STUDIO ASTE MC', 'imageUrls': {'large': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/1250133574.jpg', 'small': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/1250133572.jpg'}, 'agencyUrl': 'https://www.immobiliare.it/agenzie-immobiliari/386016/studio-aste-mc-sesto-san-giovanni/', 'address': 'Via Carlo Cattaneo 49 20099 - Sesto San Giovanni', 'bannerImage': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/image/1147591370/xs-c.jpg', 'externalId': None, 'timeContract': None, 'paid': False}, {'id': 42941, 'displayName': 'OBIETTIVOCASA', 'imageUrls': {'large': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/155958486.jpg', 'small': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/155958482.jpg'}, 'agencyUrl': 'https://www.immobiliare.it/agenzie-immobiliari/42941/obiettivocasa-milano-via-pordenone/', 'address': 'via pordenone 13 20132 - Milano', 'bannerImage': 'https://maps.im-cdn.it/static?center=45.490300,9.234840&zoom=15&size=400x230&markers=45.490300,9.234840', 'externalId': None, 'timeContract': 10, 'paid': False}, {'id': 392582, 'displayName': 'AsteGlobal', 'imageUrls': {'large': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/1227120896.jpg', 'small': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/1227120894.jpg'}, 'agencyUrl': 'https://www.immobiliare.it/agenzie-immobiliari/392582/asteblobal/', 'address': 'via Reali 13 20037 - Paderno Dugnano', 'bannerImage': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/image/1227121058/xs-c.jpg', 'externalId': None, 'timeContract': None, 'paid': False}, {'id': 203747, 'displayName': 'Le case di Patty', 'imageUrls': {'large': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/811914140.jpg', 'small': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/811914138.jpg'}, 'agencyUrl': 'https://www.immobiliare.it/agenzie-immobiliari/203747/le-case-di-patty-milano/', 'address': 'Via Montebello 14 20121 - Milano', 'bannerImage': 'https://maps.im-cdn.it/static?center=45.475200,9.189070&zoom=15&size=400x230&markers=45.475200,9.189070', 'externalId': None, 'timeContract': 7, 'paid': False}, {'id': 35498, 'displayName': "Expo'  Servizi  Immobiliari", 'imageUrls': [], 'agencyUrl': 'https://www.immobiliare.it/agenzie-immobiliari/35498/expo/', 'address': 'Viale Premuda 21 20129 - Milano', 'bannerImage': 'https://maps.im-cdn.it/static?center=45.466000,9.207020&zoom=15&size=400x230&markers=45.466000,9.207020', 'externalId': None, 'timeContract': 5, 'paid': False}, {'id': 228450, 'displayName': 'Aste Milano Immobiliare', 'imageUrls': {'large': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/1061930169.jpg', 'small': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/1061930167.jpg'}, 'agencyUrl': 'https://www.immobiliare.it/agenzie-immobiliari/228450/aste-rozzano/', 'address': 'Via Innocenzo Isimbardi 29 20141 - Milano', 'bannerImage': 'https://maps.im-cdn.it/static?center=45.435200,9.180890&zoom=15&size=400x230&markers=45.435200,9.180890', 'externalId': None, 'timeContract': 5, 'paid': False}, {'id': 5350, 'displayName': 'IMI immobiliare Milano - Partner Navigli', 'imageUrls': {'large': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/424092179.jpg', 'small': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/424092177.jpg'}, 'agencyUrl': 'https://www.immobiliare.it/agenzie-immobiliari/5350/imi-milano-navigli/', 'address': 'Via Conchetta 2 20136 - Milano', 'bannerImage': 'https://maps.im-cdn.it/static?center=45.446800,9.179270&zoom=15&size=400x230&markers=45.446800,9.179270', 'externalId': None, 'timeContract': 12, 'paid': False}, {'id': 237934, 'displayName': 'ASTA4YOU', 'imageUrls': {'large': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/1112140922.jpg', 'small': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/1112140920.jpg'}, 'agencyUrl': 'https://www.immobiliare.it/agenzie-immobiliari/237934/astayou/', 'address': 'Via Domenico Cimarosa 26 20144 - Milano', 'bannerImage': 'https://maps.im-cdn.it/static?center=45.464200,9.157880&zoom=15&size=400x230&markers=45.464200,9.157880', 'externalId': None, 'timeContract': 3, 'paid': False}, {'id': 28201, 'displayName': 'Meta Immobiliare - Massimo Valore Certificato', 'imageUrls': {'large': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/962490064.jpg', 'small': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/962490062.jpg'}, 'agencyUrl': 'https://www.immobiliare.it/agenzie-immobiliari/28201/meta-san-donato/', 'address': 'Via Alfonsine 34 20097 - San Donato Milanese', 'bannerImage': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/image/854995656/xs-c.jpg', 'externalId': None, 'timeContract': 9, 'paid': False}, {'id': 3986, 'displayName': 'TREC s.a.s', 'imageUrls': {'large': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/1040856624.jpg', 'small': 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/1040856622.jpg'}, 'agencyUrl': 'https://www.immobiliare.it/agenzie-immobiliari/3986/tre-c/', 'address': 'Via Negroli 49 20133 - Milano', 'bannerImage': 'https://maps.im-cdn.it/static?center=45.467200,9.232320&zoom=15&size=400x230&markers=45.467200,9.232320', 'externalId': None, 'timeContract': 1, 'paid': False}], 'searchAgencyUrl': 'http://www.immobiliare.it/agenzie-immobiliari/milano/?idMZona[]=10294'}
```

or with `selenium` to mimic a browser and work on the rendered `driver.page_source`.

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

url = 'https://www.immobiliare.it/vendita-case/milano/forlanini/?criterio=dataModifica&ordine=desc'
driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)

data = []
for e in soup.select('li.in-realEstateResults__item'):
    data.append({
        'title':e.a.get('title'),
        'imgUrls':[i.get('src') for i in e.select('.nd-list__item img')],
        'imgMapInfo': e.select_one('[alt="mappa"]').get('src') if e.select_one('[alt="mappa"]') else None
    })

data
```

##### Output

```
[{'title': 'Bilocale buono stato, primo piano, Viale Ungheria - Mecenate, Milano', 'imgUrls': ['https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1261450576/xxs-c.jpg', 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1261450580/xxs-c.jpg', 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1261702222/xxs-c.jpg', 'https://maps.im-cdn.it/static?zoom=15&size=360x270&language=it&style=feature%3Aroad%7Celement%3Alabels%7Cvisibility%3Aoff&sensor=false&markers=icon%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fs1.immobiliare.it%2F_next%2Fstatic%2Fmedia%2Fmap-marker.27fc2b6f.png%7C45.4565%2C9.2427&center=45.4565%2C9.2427', 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/875151762.jpg'], 'imgMapInfo': 'https://maps.im-cdn.it/static?zoom=15&size=360x270&language=it&style=feature%3Aroad%7Celement%3Alabels%7Cvisibility%3Aoff&sensor=false&markers=icon%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fs1.immobiliare.it%2F_next%2Fstatic%2Fmedia%2Fmap-marker.27fc2b6f.png%7C45.4565%2C9.2427&center=45.4565%2C9.2427'}, {'title': 'Bilocale via Romualdo Bonfadini 82, Viale Ungheria - Mecenate, Milano', 'imgUrls': ['https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1261689706/xxs-c.jpg', 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1261689762/xxs-c.jpg', 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1261689770/xxs-c.jpg', 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1261689736/xxs-c.jpg', 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1261689806/xxs-c.jpg', 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1261689780/xxs-c.jpg', 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1261689794/xxs-c.jpg', 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1261689744/xxs-c.jpg', 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1261689718/xxs-c.jpg', 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1261689728/xxs-c.jpg', 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1261689628/xxs-c.jpg', 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1261689636/xxs-c.jpg', 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1261689752/xxs-c.jpg', 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1261689674/xxs-c.jpg', 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1261689694/xxs-c.jpg', 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1261689680/xxs-c.jpg', 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1261689690/xxs-c.jpg', 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1261689670/xxs-c.jpg', 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1261689652/xxs-c.jpg', 'https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1261689816/xxs-c.jpg', 'https://maps.im-cdn.it/static?zoom=15&size=360x270&language=it&style=feature%3Aroad%7Celement%3Alabels%7Cvisibility%3Aoff&sensor=false&markers=icon%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fs1.immobiliare.it%2F_next%2Fstatic%2Fmedia%2Fmap-marker.27fc2b6f.png%7C45.4442%2C9.2417&center=45.4442%2C9.2417', 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/949757836.jpg'], 'imgMapInfo': 'https://maps.im-cdn.it/static?zoom=15&size=360x270&language=it&style=feature%3Aroad%7Celement%3Alabels%7Cvisibility%3Aoff&sensor=false&markers=icon%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fs1.immobiliare.it%2F_next%2Fstatic%2Fmedia%2Fmap-marker.27fc2b6f.png%7C45.4442%2C9.2417&center=45.4442%2C9.2417'}, {'title': 'Appartamento via Oreste Salomone, Viale Ungheria - Mecenate, Milano', 'imgUrls': ['https://pwm.im-cdn.it/image/1256189648/xxs-c.jpg', 'https://pic.im-cdn.it/imagenoresize/994952108.jpg'], 'imgMapInfo': None},...]
```

Comment: Answered your question  with this specific focus here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75059884/14460824

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="in-mediaContent">
   <div class="nd-figure in-photo in-Card__photo--big">
       <div class="nd-figure__image nd-ratio">
           ::before
          <div class="nd-slideshow nd-slideshow--small">
              <div class="nd-slideshow__content>
              </div>
                  <div class="nd-slideshow__item
                  </div>
                  <div class="nd-slideshow__item
                  </div>
                  <div class="nd-slideshow__desired_item
                      <img src =”desired link”>
                 </div>
               </div>
            </div>
       </div>
   </div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

r = soup.select('div[class*="nd-slideshow"]')
print(r)
```

in result html after `::before`

```
[<div class="nd-slideshow nd-slideshow--small">
<div <="" class="nd-slideshow__content&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;div class=" div="" nd-slideshow__item="">
<div <img="" class="nd-slideshow__item &lt;/div&gt; &lt;div class=" link”="" nd-slideshow__desired_item="" src="”desired">
</div>
</div>
</div>, <div <="" class="nd-slideshow__content&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;div class=" div="" nd-slideshow__item="">
<div <img="" class="nd-slideshow__item &lt;/div&gt; &lt;div class=" link”="" nd-slideshow__desired_item="" src="”desired">
</div>
</div>, <div <img="" class="nd-slideshow__item &lt;/div&gt; &lt;div class=" link”="" nd-slideshow__desired_item="" src="”desired">
</div>]
```

Comment: It does not work for me, added the real url and html code in the thread

Comment: what url? we need more code to reproduce problem. is it dynamic page? maybe your thread doesn't wait while element appears?

Comment: as you can see problem is not in html code, but lost quotes bothers me

Comment: https://www.immobiliare.it/vendita-case/milano/forlanini/?criterio=dataModifica&ordine=desc

Comment: Specifically I can retrieve the img src from the first property but the rest of them have a different html structure.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshot, I searched the `div` element that has the "`nd-slideshow__item in-realEstateListCard__mapInfo`" class and then I could get the image inside the "div" element.

With this idea, I've modified your code as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  
url = "https://www.immobiliare.it/vendita-case/milano/forlanini/?criterio=dataModifica&ordine=desc"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")

# The image you want is inside a img HTML element which is contained inside a "div" element: 
div_element = soup.find_all("div", class_="nd-slideshow__item in-realEstateListCard__mapInfo")

# Print the "src" value of the img HTML element found on the div
print(div_element[0].find("img")["src"])
```

And this is the result I got:

```
https://maps.im-cdn.it/static?zoom=15&size=360x270&language=it&style=feature%3Aroad%7Celement%3Alabels%7Cvisibility%3Aoff&sensor=false&markers=icon%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fs1.immobiliare.it%2F_next%2Fstatic%2Fmedia%2Fmap-marker.27fc2b6f.png%7C45.4565%2C9.2427&center=45.4565%2C9.2427
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but as I said this would only pick the src for the first property and not for the rest.