# Selenium not able to find all elements in HTML page

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I am doing web scraping to the real estate portal <www.immobiliare.it>

Specifically I am retrieving some information from the search page, which contains 25 properties per page. I have managed to retrieved almost everything but I am having trouble to retrieve the src of a map image that each property has. This map is after a CSS selector.

The HTML structure is the following:
[image: Each li class="nd-list__item in-realEstateResults__item" is a property I want to extract the img src from]

I have been able to get this data with selenium:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75020969/14461986

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

Options = Options()
Options.headless = True

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=Options, service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
url = 'https://www.immobiliare.it/vendita-case/milano/forlanini/?criterio=dataModifica&ordine=desc&page=3'
driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)

data = []

# Each property is contained under each li in-realEstateResults__item
for property in soup.select('li.in-realEstateResults__item'):

    data.append({
            'id': property.get('id'),
            'MapUrl': property.select_one('[alt="mappa"]').get('src') if property.select_one('[alt="mappa"]') else None
        })

print(data)
```

However, after the 4th image the MapUrl comes empty. The properties are correcty loaded as I have checked the Ids and also the HTML for the rest of the images is the same but for a reason I do not understand the MapUrl is not retrieved. I would also welcome any advice on how make this script more efficient.

Comment: Could it be that this this element is not displayed but rather somewhere off-screen?

Comment: Manually you can pass the images and reach the map for each property. Additionally, by inspecting the html code in the browser you can find each of the map src aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However, issue here is lazy loading, so you have to interact with the website and scroll down to force the loading.

You may have to accept / close some popups (optional):

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#didomi-notice-agree-button').click()
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.nd-dialogFrame__close').click()
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'section h1').click()
```

now we can start scrolling (simple but working solution, could be improved):

```
for i in range(30):
        driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'body').send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
        time.sleep(0.3)
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

url = 'https://www.immobiliare.it/vendita-case/milano/forlanini/?criterio=dataModifica&ordine=desc'
driver.get(url)


driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#didomi-notice-agree-button').click()
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.nd-dialogFrame__close').click()
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'section h1').click()

for i in range(30):
        driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'body').send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
        time.sleep(0.3)


soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)

data = []
for e in soup.select('li.in-realEstateResults__item'):
    data.append({
        'title':e.a.get('title'),
        'imgUrls':[i.get('src') for i in e.select('.nd-list__item img')],
        'imgMapInfo': e.select_one('[alt="mappa"]').get('src') if e.select_one('[alt="mappa"]') else None
    })

data
```

Comment: The only modification I would add is:
This two after several executions (opening several pages with the same driver) seems to fail, If i remove them the script works perfectly.
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#didomi-notice-agree-button').click()
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.nd-dialogFrame__close').click()

Comment: That is correct, if it goes beyond the example and further result pages are to be processed, I would check for the existence of the elements and execute the actions in dependence on them or design the flow in such a way that they are only used initially when called and encapsulate the iteration of the pages.

Comment: For me the script works without clicking those elements, so I have decided to remove them.

Comment: In terms of efficiency, is there a way to make this process faster? I have just used Options.headless = True for the driver but I would need to make it even lighter

Comment: While I was looking deeper into it, I was able to come up with a `requests` and `beautifulsoup` solution. The forest for the trees - I never stop learning. Corrected my initial approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/75020969/14461986

Comment: I have developed my algorithm based on your answer (I extract much more data) and the solution is amazing. It goes superfast. Thank you so much!