# How to get web page images using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, web-crawler

I tried to save the images in the following way:

```
res=requests.get(url,headers=headers)
bs=BeautifulSoup(res.content,"html.parser")
images=bs.find_all("img")
for i,img in enumerate(images):
    try:
        img_url=img['src']
        print(img_url)
        if img_url[-1]=="g":
            res=requests.get(img_url)
            f=open(f"{name}/image_{i}.jpg","wb")
            f.write(res.content)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

But some images are not saved and the result of printing their `src` is as follows:

```
'src'
'src'
'src'
```

I guess it's because it's taking a while to load, what can I do?

Comment: What's the website?

Comment: https://www.farfetch.com/uk/shopping/men/burberry-check-print-stretch-cotton-shirt-item-19844301.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue here is that the images are lazy loaded when they come into view. So there are several options to get your goal:

**Option#1**

Use `selenium` to mimic a browser, automate scrolling and render full source -> [similar topic exmaple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75059384/selenium-not-able-to-find-all-elements-in-html-page)

**Option#2**

Even simpler, use your modules and check the website for script contents that contain your information - This is for the main product and its four images:

```
data = json.loads(
        BeautifulSoup(
            res.content,
            "html.parser"
        ).select_one('script[type="application/ld+json"]').text
    )
```

In addition to access the attributes:

> KeyError: [attr] - Caused by accessing tag['attr'] when the tag in
> question doesn’t define the attr attribute. The most common errors are
> KeyError: 'href' and KeyError: 'class'. Use tag.get('attr') if you’re
> not sure attr is defined, just as you would with a Python dictionary.

##### Example

```
import requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url='https://www.farfetch.com/uk/shopping/men/burberry-check-print-stretch-cotton-shirt-item-19844301.aspx'
res=requests.get(url, headers = {'user-agent':'some agent'})

data = json.loads(
            BeautifulSoup(
                res.content,
                "html.parser"
            ).select_one('script[type="application/ld+json"]').text
        )
```

##### Output

```
{'@context': 'https://schema.org',
 '@type': 'Product',
 'name': 'check print stretch-cotton shirt',
 'image': [{'@type': 'ImageObject',
   'contentUrl': 'https://cdn-images.farfetch-contents.com/19/84/43/01/19844301_44552233_1000.jpg',
   'description': 'Burberry check print stretch-cotton shirt'},
  {'@type': 'ImageObject',
   'contentUrl': 'https://cdn-images.farfetch-contents.com/19/84/43/01/19844301_44676163_1000.jpg',
   'description': 'Burberry check print stretch-cotton shirt'},
  {'@type': 'ImageObject',
   'contentUrl': 'https://cdn-images.farfetch-contents.com/19/84/43/01/19844301_44552234_1000.jpg',
   'description': 'Burberry check print stretch-cotton shirt'},
  {'@type': 'ImageObject',
   'contentUrl': 'https://cdn-images.farfetch-contents.com/19/84/43/01/19844301_44552232_1000.jpg',
   'description': 'Burberry check print stretch-cotton shirt'}],
 'productID': '19844301',
 'brand': {'@type': 'Brand', 'name': 'Burberry'},
 'offers': {'@type': 'Offer',
  'url': 'https://www.farfetch.com/shopping/men/burberry-check-print-stretch-cotton-shirt-item-19844301.aspx',
  'priceCurrency': 'GBP',
  'price': 470,
  'availability': 'https://schema.org/InStock',
  'itemCondition': 'https://schema.org/NewCondition'}}
```

Simply iterate the output to get your image urls:

```
for img in data.get('image'):
    print(img.get('contentUrl'))
```

->

```
https://cdn-images.farfetch-contents.com/19/84/43/01/19844301_44552233_1000.jpg
https://cdn-images.farfetch-contents.com/19/84/43/01/19844301_44676163_1000.jpg
https://cdn-images.farfetch-contents.com/19/84/43/01/19844301_44552234_1000.jpg
https://cdn-images.farfetch-contents.com/19/84/43/01/19844301_44552232_1000.jpg
```